# Babel not working with ES6 / Parser.pp.raise

Tags: mocha.js, babeljs

It's very confusing with all these errors when I try to install babel and get it working, hope someone can help!

.babel_src

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "testing-application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha './src/**/*.spec.js' --compilers js:babel-core/register"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.5.0",
    "except": "^0.1.3",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Unexpected token (3:20)
  1 | import except from 'except';
  2 | 
> 3 | describe('empty' () => {
    |                     ^
  4 |   it("should workd", () => {
  5 |     except(true).toEqual(true);
  6 |   })
    at Parser.pp.raise(/Users/tests/Documents/React-Redux-Applications/TestingApplication/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1378:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had error in the ES6 code! Sorry for the mistake!